# Trivial colouring and the fundamental group of a knot

Tags: knot-theory, knot-invariants

Suppose that a classical knot diagram $K$ is coloured by a finite quandle $X$ such that only one element in the quandle is used to colour the knot $K$. We say that the colouring is trivial in this case. Is the follwoing statement true: If the knot admit only trivial colouring by any finite quandle, then can we conclude that the fundmental group of the knot is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$?

Answer (score 0):

For a quick review of part of Joyce's 1980 paper: Given a quandle $Q$ and a group $G$, there is a quandle $\operatorname{Conj} G$ whose operation is conjugation ($g\triangleright h:=h^{-1}gh$), and there is a group $\operatorname{Adconj} Q$ generated by the elements of $Q$ with the relations $y^{-1}xy=x\triangleright y$ for all $x,y\in Q$.  Quandle maps $Q\to \operatorname{Conj}H$ are in one-to-one correspondence with group homomorphisms $\operatorname{Adconj Q}\to H$.

If every quandle map $Q\to R$ with $R$ a finite quandle is trivial, then it follows that for every finite group $H$, every group homomorphism $\operatorname{Adconj}Q\to H$ has abelian image.

For knots, the fundamental quandle's Adconj is the fundamental group of the knot complement.  Thus, we may assume the finite quotients of $\pi_1(S^3-K)$ are all abelian.  Since the abelianization is $H_1(S^3-K)\cong\mathbb{Z}$, all the finite quotients are in fact cyclic, and furthermore the finite quotients consist of *all* the finite cyclic groups.  The only group whose finite quotients are all the finite cyclic groups is $\mathbb{Z}$ itself due to its *profinite rigidity*.  (So $K$ must be the unknot.)

Comment: I don't understand how to define the group Adconj $Q$ generated by the elements of the quandle $Q$, $y \in Q$ so what is the meaning of $y^{-1}$?

Comment: To be more formal: for all $x\in Q$, let $g_x$ be a new letter.  Then, $\operatorname{Adconj}Q=\langle \{g_x:x\in Q\}\mid\forall x,y\in Q, g_{x\triangleright y}=g_y^{-1}g_xg_y\rangle$.  Answering your question, $y^{-1}$ is a formal inverse of $y$, and in this new notation, it is $g_y^{-1}$.  When $Q$ is a trivial quandle, $\operatorname{Adconj}Q$ is an abelian group because the relations are commutators.  For example, if $Q$ is the fundamental quandle of the unknot (which means $Q$ has exactly one element $x_0$), then $\operatorname{Adconj}Q=\langle g_{x_0}\rangle\cong \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: I see, thank you so much Kyle Miller.

Comment: @user113715 I notice you have only ever accepted one answer out of all your questions.  Please consider voting and/or accepting answers to your questions, or commenting if the answers were insufficient.

Comment: The answer above really giving me a hint, If a hint is given then I can get the whole answer.

Comment: @user113715 I do not understand what you are saying.  Did this answer help you figure out the answer to your question or not?

Comment: Yes, I got. If the quandle is trivial, then the group associated to the qandle is an abelian group. If we talk about knots, this is the fundamental group of the knot. In addition, if the knot is coloured trivially by only one element in any quandle, then the fundamental quandle is the quandle genertaed by one element, and the group associated to it is the fundamental group whis is a cyclic abelian group generated by one element, so it must be $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @user113715 I see you simplified the argument to "the fundamental quandle colors itself."  I missed the part where you defined "trivial" to mean "there are only colorings by a single element" rather than "the image is a trivial quandle," which is more difficult yet still true.  Anyway, you're meant to accept an answer to indicate that you aren't awaiting any more help (even if you feel the answer was only a "hint"), to respect others' time.